# Use Publisher protocol

Tags: swift, generics, combine

I want to hide my publisher implementation:

```swift
public protocol MyPublisher: Combine.Publisher where Failure == Never, Output == MyType {
    ...
}

internal struct MyPublisherImpl: MyPublisher {
    public typealias Output = MyType
    public typealias Failure = Never
    private let wrappedPublisher: SomeKnownPublisher

    public func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S : Subscriber, Never == S.Failure, Output == S.Input {
        wrappedPublisher
            .map{ <convert to MyType> }
            .subscribe(subscriber)
    }

    ...
}

public func makeMyPublisher(...) -> any MyPublisher { 
    return MyPublisherImpl(...)
}
```

```swift
let myPublisher = makeMyPublisher(...)

myPublisher
    .assign(to:\.keyPath, on: someObject)
    .store(in: &cancellables)
```

It works great until I need to use any function on my publisher:

```swift
let anotherMyPublisher = makeMyPublisher(...)

anotherMyPublisher
    .map{...}
    .assign(to:\.anotherKeyPath, on: anotherObject)
    .store(in: &cancellables)
```

In this case I have an error:

> Member 'map' cannot be used on value of type 'any MyPublisher'; consider using a generic constraint instead

When I remove 'where' from protocol, I get the same error about '.assign(to: on:)'.

What must I do to use MyPublisher as any other usual publisher?

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem you are having is that a variable of type `any MyPublisher` is not a `MyPublisher`.  `any MyPublisher` is an Existential.

What you are saying is "there exists at least one type that implements `MyPublisher's` interface. I want you to create me a box that can hold a value of any such type".  (you are declaring that at least one concrete type "exists" that implements the abstract `MyPubisher` interface hence the term "existential").

A variable that is of type `any MyPublisher` is a box that can hold any type that implements `MyPubisher` but, and this is critical, *the box itself does not implement `MyPublisher's` interface.*

It's a box that holds a `MyPublisher`, but is not a `MyPublisher` itself so it doesn't have functions like `map` on it.

What you probably want is for `makeMyPubisher` to return `some MyPublisher`. That is return an entity of a specific type where that conforms to `MyPublisher`, instead of a box that can contain any type of thing that implements `MyPubisher`.